# " Appearance" setting is missing after updating to 22.04

Tags: system-installation

Using Ubuntu in French, I updated to 22.04 yesterday, August 17th and it seems to be incorrect after re-boot. The dock is at the bottom about 1 inch height, I want the dock on the left.

The dock position is normally available in the settings. However, **Appearance** is missing from the settings list.

[image: Screen dock at bottom][image: English settings][image: French settings]

[image: Gnome tweak]

[image: Extensions Manager 1]

[image: Extensions Manager 2]

[image: Image in double]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138681/discussion-on-question-by-gill-appearance-setting-is-missing-after-updating-to).

Comment: A- why this change
B-How do I get Appearance to appear in Settings
C-How do I get Extensions to appear in Tweaks
D- If you go back to the top of this page and look at word Extension there is a small red circle = out dated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dconf /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock
autohide
Dock shown on mouse over (panneau apparaît touche le côté) Activé le bouton

Dconf /org/gnome/shell/extensions/mmod-panel/panel-position
Valeur personnalisée  LeftSide

Dconf /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock
dock-position LEFT

But Appearance and Extensions missing
Appearance will be in Settings only with Ubuntu Desktop not with Gnome Desktop
For Extensions have to use Gnome Extensions via Internet with Firefox but not Firefox from Snap (You have to install Google Chrome to get Gnome extensions)
Plus you could install Extensions Manager